# jquery callback html and json

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery which passes variables to a php file, the php file generates dynamic html content based on these variables to be passed back which I then use for updating the page.

However I also want to return some variables also so I can then decide how and where to display the html content.

The only way I have found so far seems a little crude and I'm sure a better way exists.

At the moment the php file puts the generated content in a tag like so

```
<content>CONTENT HERE</content>
```

Then I use another tag for the var's I also want to return.

```
<json>{"name" : "value"}</json>
```

Then I have this on the ajax callback

```
content = $(data).find('content').html();
json = $(data).find('json').text();
```

Comment: so are you returning `xml` from php?

Comment: Are you returning a JSON encoded in XML? You may know that JSON and XML are "concurrents", and generally JSON is preferred (because it's a native JS object, doesn't need parsing etc.) Why encode one in another's format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use json output rather than a hybrid xml/json mix.

In php

```
$output=array(
   'content'=> $htmlVariable,
   'data'=> $resultsArray
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Then in js:

```
$.getJSON('path/to/server',{/* data if applicable*/}, function(response){
      var content = response.content;
      var data = response.data;
});
```

This way jQuery will manage the json string parsing for you.

You can assign any html you want to an object property or in an array and `json_encode` will take care of all necessary escaping

Comment: I was looking at this as a possible, but wasnt sure if i could pass any html though a json or the ammount of html would pose a problem?

Comment: no problem at all ... I do this all the time. Remember that html is just a string until it gets parsed into the DOM by browser